# ASP.NET Bundling and Minification removing license comments?

Tags: asp.net, bundling-and-minification

Is there any way to stop asp.net from removing important comments (license, `/*! content */`)  when Bundling and Minifying javascript files with `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization`? im not 100% sure but removing it from the result would be illegal?

Comment: Yeah. I built a nuget package to do this. https://www.nuget.org/packages/LicensedBundler/ and wrote about it [in a little more detail here](http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/keep-important-licensing-comments-dotnet-bundling-minification/). Source code [is here](https://github.com/MikeSmithDev/LicensedBundler). Still don't know why they do this because I agree... seems like makes you non-compliant with their licensing.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev thanks that worked, i only wish that you didn't add `/*! Bundled by LicensedBundler | www.nuget.org/packages/LicensedBundler/ | @MikeSmithDev mikesmithdev.com */`, but its still better then before.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev im a sneaky guy :) but your addition doesn't seems like a license more like an ad that no one sees.

Comment: Valid point... next time I'll mask my self-promotion under more "licensey" sounding text :)